# I like to travel. Can you tell where I've been?

Tags: lateral-thinking

I live in a cold country, and each year I travel to one of my four favorite summer destinations: Valencia, Tel Aviv, Sydney or Porto.

I have a habit of visiting my grandmother when I return (same day or the day after) and when I meet her she would say, without knowing where I've been, "How was X?" (X being one of the four cities I mentioned).

She would often guess wrong, but I've noticed something strange. She has almost 100% success when it comes to Valencia. When I've been there she would always say "How was Valencia?" and she'd never say it when I've been someplace else. The rest of the time, seems like she's just guessing.

When I asked her how she knows, she only replies "because I'm perceptive, and you're irresponsible".

Can you help me figure out how she does it?

Comment: Damn I had an answer if it was Sydney :(

Comment: @Saeïdryl what?

Comment: I had an answer if she has 100% if it comes to *Sydney* and not Valencia :(

Comment: what's was the answer? ;)

Comment: Sydney will be in winter so that will be the only trip you returned from not tanned

Comment: actually that's a good point, I meant to say that you travel to those places when it's summer there

Comment: In that case, it would be the only trip you make during the winter.

Comment: Also, it doesn't have anything to do with forgetting to remove the airplane tag from your suitcase, only if you've been to Valencia?

Comment: @PL457 it's true, but still you won't get 100% accuracy because the off-seasons of those places do overlap (right now for example is a good time to be in any of those places). And to your second question - no :)

Comment: You commented "you travel to those places when it's summer there" and "right now for example is a good time to be in any of those place" which might be true but right now it's not summer in Valencia or Porto. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @NashVio by summer I mean any time that's warm

Comment: @Dotan "Spring or Autumn" would have been less confusing, as the temperatures would have been the same in either hemisphere :P

Comment: Ahhh damn, I thought it was going to be a sunburn related answer too.

Comment: Is the answer something that could involve the [knowledge] tag?  Maybe something like (dumb example) your breath smells of something you ate peculiar to Valencian cuisine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "summer" destinations? One of your comments says, "the off-seasons of those places do overlap". Which implies "summer" has nothing to do with anything.  Also, can we assume that "almost 100%" actually ought to be "exactly 100%"? Otherwise is this a clue?

Comment: There are several answers that could be the answer, but aren't. Can you tighten up the clues so it's not so broad? Or are we missing a clue?

Comment: Does she *“almost”* always or *”always”* guess Valencia right? More importantly, does it even matter?

Comment: i envy you so much.

Comment: Needs a "longitudinal thinking" tag.

Comment: Hmmmmm. She maybe has a secret spanish sister who reports all your adventures to her?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your grandmother knows you've been in Valencia because

> you come back with a stronger tan (or sunburn) on the *right* side of your face.

This is because...

> When you vacation, you like to tan on the beach all day (or surf, or swim).

and

> When tanning, you like to face the ocean (or, when surfing/swimming all day, you spend most of your time facing towards the ocean, b/c more time is spent swimming outwards than inwards because of the surf).

and

> Valencia and Sydney have beaches with the ocean to the east; Porto and Tel-Aviv have beaches with the ocean to the west.

and

> Sydney is the south hemisphere, so the sun is in the north; the others are all in the north hemisphere, so the sun is in the south.

and

> In Valencia, you get a tan on the right side of your face (facing east, sun south);  but in the others, you get a tan on the left side of your face (Porto + Tel Aviv: facing west, sun south; Sydney: facing east, sun north)

You are irresponsible because...

> you don't use sunscreen (you don't have the habit, because your "cold country" doesn't get much sun)

Your grandmother is perceptive because...

> She notices the difference in tans, and figures out all of the above.

Comment: Good job! I was sure I would need to add more clues :)

Comment: Clever - I'd noticed the East/West thing, but hadn't taken North/South into account so discarded that as a potential answer. :(

Comment: There are lots of assumptions here. Maybe sunbathes at a hotel pool and not the ocean.

Answer (score 19):

My guess is that

> You live in Norway or Sweden, which are both cold countries in the same timezone as Valencia.

Your grandmother would know because

> She noticed your watch is always displaying the wrong time when you return from one of the other destinations since you always forget to resynchronize (hence the "irresponsible", you could be late for work the next day!)
>  However, when you come back from Valencia, you didn't have to change the time so it's the same as in your country.

Also, this assumes

> That your grandmother doesn't really know the timelag of the other destinations, or she would be able to deduce them as well by comparing the shift in the hours.

Comment: Good try! But my grandma is very sharp and would easily be able to tell the other countries apart by the time shift. Also, who wears a watch these days? :)

Comment: @Dotan Grandma is apparently not smart enough to notice that you vacation during the summer for one destination and during the winter for the other three.

Answer (score 19):

I believe you live in...

> Russia, specifically the eastern past of Russia.

And when you visit Valencia...

> you are actually visiting [Valencia, Venezuela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencia,_Carabobo), as opposed to [Valencia, Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencia). Traveling from here back to Eastern Russia will likely lead to you crossing the [International Date Line](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dateline.html) from East to West (which wouldn't happen for the other vacation spots), thereby causing you to add a day.

Your grandmother thinks you're irresponsible because...

> you always forget this, and show up a day later than you said you would (i.e. the day you left). You said you visit her on the "same day or the day after", and every time it's the day after she assumes you came from Valencia and forgot again.

Comment: Interesting theory, albeit not very plausible :) I was referring to Valencia, Spain

Comment: Pity. I liked this answer :)

Comment: I was studying up on different Valencias around the world as well.

Comment: Yes crossing date lines can be irresponsible. Maybe it was a hidden date word joke.

Answer (score 11):

She knows you went to Valencia because

> contrary to Israel, Australia and, in a lesser measure, Portugal, Spain is [very liberal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_Spain) regarding cannabis cultivation and use, and your eyes indicate without doubt that you have been smoking (irresponsibly) all day long during your holidays.

Answer (score 5):

she knows you've been to Valencia because

> you visit wearing the new silk clothes you bought because Valencia is famous for its [silk exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llotja_de_la_Seda).

you are irresponsible because

> it is very expensive and does not keep you warm in your home country

Comment: Give me some credit, if I this was it I would know

Answer (score 3):

she knows

> you have a girlfriend in Valencia

and when you go other places

> you actually spend time outdoors and get a tan

but in Valencia

> you spend all of your 'irresponsible' time in the bedroom, hence coming back without a tan.

Comment: What's so irresponsible about that? My grandma is quite liberal in those things

Answer (score 2):

When you return from Valencia you always bring back

> oranges

This is irresponsible because

> you are not supposed to bring fruit back from another country

Answer (score 1):

> If your grandmother says Valencia each time you come back from holidays, then each time you go to Valencia she will make the correct guess.

Comment: I like this answer. OP didn't say that his grandma mixes up her guesses, just that when they go to Tel Aviv, Sydney, or Port she guesses wrong, which makes sense if she guessed Valencia.

Comment: Although OP does say “she’d never say it when I’ve been somewhere else”

Answer (score 1):

Because

> your clothes smell like fireworks from the Fallas Festival that occurs every afternoon

and

> you are irresponsible because you haven't washed your clothes which smell like the fireworks from the same festival.

Answer (score 0):

> Your grandmother knows you've been to **Valencia** because you still have the Magic Mountain stamp on your hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea how you’re irresponsible. I don’t know anything about these cities. But if my guess turns out to be right, I’ll learn something about their climates.

> You have a new umbrella. You’re irresponsible because you forget to pack your umbrella, so you have to buy a new one when it rains in Valencia. (The other cities don’t get much rain.)